# How to locate the Occurrences of a Specific value in pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-loc, python-applymap

I want to locate a specific value which can occur in multiple columns . In my case it's  "False" .
I know how to search "False" in individual columns as

```
df.loc[df['column1']==False]
df.loc[df['column2']==False]
```

Is there a way to find all at once ?

```
Unnamed: 0  Incident ID CR Number   Victims Zip Code    Address Number  Latitude    Longitude   Year    Month   Day
0   False   False   True    True    True    True    True    True    True    True    True
1   False   True    False   False   True    True    True    True    True    True    True
2   True    True    True    True    True    True    False   True    True    True    True
3   True    True    False   True    True    True    True    True    True    True    True
4   True    True    True    True    True    True    True    True    False   True    True
```

I want to see their locations .Hopefully something like

```
df.applymap.loc(False)
```

Comment: "I want to see their locations". How do you want to see them, i.e., how exactly should the output look like? A list of row index/column name positions? A dataframe with "X" values where the occurrences are? Etc.

Comment: `s = df.stack() ; s[~s]` (`s[s.eq(False)]` if you have values other than `True`/`False`) or if you want to assign: `df[~df] = 'X'` / `df[df.eq(False)] = 'X'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the indices `stack`, then slice:

```
s = df.stack()
s[s.eq(False)].index
```

Or if you only have `True`/`False`:

```
s[~s].index
```

In one line:

```
df.stack().loc[lambda s: ~s].index
```

If you want to assign value(s) on the `False` positions, a simple boolean indexing will do:

```
df[df.eq(False)] = 'X'`

# or, if only True/False in the df 
df[~df] = 'X'`
```